# What is the penalty for taking off your helmet in an NFL game?

Tags: nfl

During the [Atlanta Falcons and Carolina Panthers game](https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/34948608/panthers-dj-moore-regret-unsportsmanlike-penalty-falcons), a penalty was called on DJ Moore for taking his helmet off while on the field. However, during the [Tampa Bay Buccaneers and Los Angeles Rams game](https://thespun.com/nfl/refs-missed-big-penalty-in-bucs-vs-rams-finish), Jalen Ramsey was not penalized for taking off his helmet while on the field.

What is the right call here, according to NFL rules? Is there a penalty for taking off your helmet during a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [NFL Rulebook](https://operations.nfl.com/media/5kvgzyss/2022-nfl-rulebook-final.pdf), rule 12, section 3, article 1;

> ARTICLE 1. PROHIBITED ACTS. There shall be no unsportsmanlike conduct. This applies to any act which is contrary to the generally understood principles of sportsmanship. Such acts specifically include, among others:
>
> > (h) Removal of his helmet by a player in the field of play or the end zone during a celebration or demonstration, or during a confrontation with a game official or any other player.

So, just taking it off because your head is itchy will not generally be flagged, but doing so as part of a celebration or protest will be.

As to whether it should have been called in any one instance - no comment there, it's very much up to the referee's discretion.